# How can I use my own data to test this Convolutional Neural Network on PyTorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

so recently I have been following this tutorial from sentdex on convolutional neural networks and I have been trying to implement his code to test the trained neural network with my own images (in this case, I just pick random pictures from the dataset used in his program). So my intention is to train the neural network, test it and finally save it so I can later load it on a separate python file to use the already trained NN on one single image.

The dataset he uses is "dogs vs cats from microsoft". This is the code where I wrote the neural network program ("main.py").

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim

REBUILD_DATA = False # set to true to one once, then back to false unless you want to change something in your training data.

class DogsVSCats():
    IMG_SIZE = 100
    CATS = "PetImages/Cat"
    DOGS = "PetImages/Dog"
    TESTING = "PetImages/Testing"
    LABELS = {CATS: 0, DOGS: 1}
    training_data = []

    catcount = 0
    dogcount = 0

    def make_training_data(self):
        for label in self.LABELS:
            print(label)
            for f in tqdm(os.listdir(label)):
                if "jpg" in f:
                    try:
                        path = os.path.join(label, f)
                        img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                        img = cv2.resize(img, (self.IMG_SIZE, self.IMG_SIZE))
                        self.training_data.append([np.array(img), np.eye(2)[self.LABELS[label]]])  # do something like print(np.eye(2)[1]), just makes one_hot
                        #print(np.eye(2)[self.LABELS[label]])

                        if label == self.CATS:
                            self.catcount += 1
                        elif label == self.DOGS:
                            self.dogcount += 1

                    except Exception as e:
                        pass
                        #print(label, f, str(e))

        np.random.shuffle(self.training_data)
        np.save("training_data.npy", self.training_data)
        print('Cats:',dogsvcats.catcount)
        print('Dogs:',dogsvcats.dogcount)


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() # just run the init of parent class (nn.Module)
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 5) # input is 1 image, 32 output channels, 5x5 kernel / window
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 5) # input is 32, bc the first layer output 32. Then we say the output will be 64 channels, 5x5 kernel / window
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 5)

        x = torch.randn(50, 50).view(-1, 1, 50, 50)
        self._to_linear = None
        self.convs(x)

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self._to_linear, 512) #flattening.
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 2) # 512 in, 2 out bc we're doing 2 classes (dog vs cat).

    def convs(self, x):
        # max pooling over 2x2
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), (2, 2))
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)), (2, 2))
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv3(x)), (2, 2))

        if self._to_linear is None:
            self._to_linear = x[0].shape[0]*x[0].shape[1]*x[0].shape[2]
        return x

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.convs(x)
        x = x.view(-1, self._to_linear)  # .view is reshape ... this flattens X before
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x) # bc this is our output layer. No activation here.
        return F.softmax(x, dim=1)


net = Net()

print(net)

if REBUILD_DATA:
    dogsvcats = DogsVSCats()
    dogsvcats.make_training_data()

training_data = np.load("training_data.npy", allow_pickle=True)
print(len(training_data))

optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)
loss_function = nn.MSELoss()

X = torch.Tensor([i[0] for i in training_data]).view(-1,50,50)
X = X/255.0
y = torch.Tensor([i[1] for i in training_data])

VAL_PCT = 0.1  # lets reserve 10% of our data for validation
val_size = int(len(X)*VAL_PCT)

train_X = X[:-val_size]
train_y = y[:-val_size]

test_X = X[-val_size:]
test_y = y[-val_size:]

BATCH_SIZE = 100
EPOCHS = 1

def train(net):
    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
        for i in tqdm(range(0, len(train_X), BATCH_SIZE)): # from 0, to the len of x, stepping BATCH_SIZE at a time. [:50] ..for now just to dev
            #print(f"{i}:{i+BATCH_SIZE}")
            batch_X = train_X[i:i+BATCH_SIZE].view(-1, 1, 50, 50)
            batch_y = train_y[i:i+BATCH_SIZE]

            net.zero_grad()

            outputs = net(batch_X)
            loss = loss_function(outputs, batch_y)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()    # Does the update

        print(f"Epoch: {epoch}. Loss: {loss}")

def test(net):
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for i in tqdm(range(len(test_X))):
            real_class = torch.argmax(test_y[i])
            net_out = net(test_X[i].view(-1, 1, 50, 50))[0]  # returns a list,
            predicted_class = torch.argmax(net_out)

            if predicted_class == real_class:
                correct += 1
            total += 1

    print("Accuracy: ", round(correct/total, 3))

train(net)
test(net)

PATH = './object_detection.pth'
torch.save(net.state_dict(), PATH)
```

After training the neural network, I want to load it in this next program and simply test the images on the NN. However, every time I run this program, the neural network is trained and tested again, which makes this process much longer and annoying. And also, I think when I run this program and then input the image into the NN, the whole "main.py" is being run.

Please, can someone help me with this? It would be amazing, as I am using this as a base to my Bachelor's thesis. Potentially I would also like to adapt this code to run my own entire dataset through it, it would be incredible if someone would help me do this, as I am a newbie on pytorch.

```
import cv2
from main import Net, train, test
import numpy as np

classes = ('cat', 'dog')

imsize = 50

net = Net()
net.load_state_dict(torch.load('./object_detection.pth'))


def image_loader(image_name):
    image = cv2.imread(image_name, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (imsize, imsize))
    image = np.array(image)
    image = torch.Tensor(image)/255
    image = image.view(-1, 1, 50, 50)
    return image


test_image = image_loader("./PetImages/Cat/1021.jpg")

result = net(test_image)
_, predicted = torch.max(result, 1)


print(result)
print(classes[predicted[0]])
```

Comment: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html You need to save your model. WHen you want to 'evaluate' your model on your entire dataset, you simply need to load the model with your new dataset and just evaluate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is nothing related to NN, but the importing part.

In the second code snippet, you import classes and functions your first code snippet. At the same time, the statements will also be executed all the code inside and it is not what we want.

The simplest way to solve it is to collect your code inside a if case to avoid execution during being imported.

The result may look like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim


class DogsVSCats():
    IMG_SIZE = 100
    CATS = "PetImages/Cat"
    DOGS = "PetImages/Dog"
    TESTING = "PetImages/Testing"
    LABELS = {CATS: 0, DOGS: 1}
    training_data = []

    catcount = 0
    dogcount = 0

    def make_training_data(self):
        for label in self.LABELS:
            print(label)
            for f in tqdm(os.listdir(label)):
                if "jpg" in f:
                    try:
                        path = os.path.join(label, f)
                        img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                        img = cv2.resize(img, (self.IMG_SIZE, self.IMG_SIZE))
                        self.training_data.append([np.array(img), np.eye(2)[self.LABELS[label]]])  # do something like print(np.eye(2)[1]), just makes one_hot
                        #print(np.eye(2)[self.LABELS[label]])

                        if label == self.CATS:
                            self.catcount += 1
                        elif label == self.DOGS:
                            self.dogcount += 1

                    except Exception as e:
                        pass
                        #print(label, f, str(e))

        np.random.shuffle(self.training_data)
        np.save("training_data.npy", self.training_data)
        print('Cats:',dogsvcats.catcount)
        print('Dogs:',dogsvcats.dogcount)


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() # just run the init of parent class (nn.Module)
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 5) # input is 1 image, 32 output channels, 5x5 kernel / window
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 5) # input is 32, bc the first layer output 32. Then we say the output will be 64 channels, 5x5 kernel / window
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 5)

        x = torch.randn(50, 50).view(-1, 1, 50, 50)
        self._to_linear = None
        self.convs(x)

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self._to_linear, 512) #flattening.
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 2) # 512 in, 2 out bc we're doing 2 classes (dog vs cat).

    def convs(self, x):
        # max pooling over 2x2
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), (2, 2))
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)), (2, 2))
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv3(x)), (2, 2))

        if self._to_linear is None:
            self._to_linear = x[0].shape[0]*x[0].shape[1]*x[0].shape[2]
        return x

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.convs(x)
        x = x.view(-1, self._to_linear)  # .view is reshape ... this flattens X before
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x) # bc this is our output layer. No activation here.
        return F.softmax(x, dim=1)



def train(net):
    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
        for i in tqdm(range(0, len(train_X), BATCH_SIZE)): # from 0, to the len of x, stepping BATCH_SIZE at a time. [:50] ..for now just to dev
            #print(f"{i}:{i+BATCH_SIZE}")
            batch_X = train_X[i:i+BATCH_SIZE].view(-1, 1, 50, 50)
            batch_y = train_y[i:i+BATCH_SIZE]

            net.zero_grad()

            outputs = net(batch_X)
            loss = loss_function(outputs, batch_y)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()    # Does the update

        print(f"Epoch: {epoch}. Loss: {loss}")

def test(net):
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for i in tqdm(range(len(test_X))):
            real_class = torch.argmax(test_y[i])
            net_out = net(test_X[i].view(-1, 1, 50, 50))[0]  # returns a list,
            predicted_class = torch.argmax(net_out)

            if predicted_class == real_class:
                correct += 1
            total += 1

    print("Accuracy: ", round(correct/total, 3))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    REBUILD_DATA = False # set to true to one once, then back to false unless you want to change something in your training data.
    net = Net()

    print(net)

    if REBUILD_DATA:
        dogsvcats = DogsVSCats()
        dogsvcats.make_training_data()

    training_data = np.load("training_data.npy", allow_pickle=True)
    print(len(training_data))

    optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)
    loss_function = nn.MSELoss()

    X = torch.Tensor([i[0] for i in training_data]).view(-1,50,50)
    X = X/255.0
    y = torch.Tensor([i[1] for i in training_data])

    VAL_PCT = 0.1  # lets reserve 10% of our data for validation
    val_size = int(len(X)*VAL_PCT)

    train_X = X[:-val_size]
    train_y = y[:-val_size]

    test_X = X[-val_size:]
    test_y = y[-val_size:]

    BATCH_SIZE = 100
    EPOCHS = 1
    train(net)
    test(net)

    PATH = './object_detection.pth'
    torch.save(net.state_dict(), PATH)
```

You can check more information on the official docs: [import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) and [main](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This worked, however I also found out probably an even "cleaner" way to solve this by creating another python file with the neural network class. This way I can just import this class only so that the rest is not imported too and executed.

Answer (score 0):

you can save your model as a pickle file and load it to use for another program using torch.save and torch.load. So in your case when you see loss drops you can call

```
torch.save(net.state_dict(), <save_path>)  # to save
net.load_state_dict(torch.load(<save_path>))  # to load again
```

You need to track the min loss though in your train function